# The Japanese Culture Q&A proposal is in need of support!

Tags: discussion

Nine months ago, a Japanese Culture proposal was started on the Area 51 meta site.

[**Japanese Culture proposal @ Area 51**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture?referrer=NYLqfxFYemeWXYyF_kRbzQ2)

Recently, the proposal hit its goal of 60 followers, but our work is far from over. It is in dire need of more upvoted questions to label it a viable proposal; currently, we need **at least another 22 questions with 10 upvotes** to meet this goal.

We're on a bit of a tight schedule to make this proposal viable, so if you're interested in making this site happen, please help it meet its goals:

1. **Follow** the proposal!
2. **Submit** more sample questions!
3. **Vote up** questions others have written!

The Japanese Culture Q&A site proposal needs *your* support!

[image]

Comment: At this point, it doesn't really matter all that much whether or not you follow the proposal. What **does** matter is upvoting sample questions _that have a score of less than 10_. This is priority number one.

Comment: Instead of caring about other communities you should first focus on Anime & Manga so it doesn't get close by the end of beta which looks very likely since it doesn't met any of the points that define it as a healthy community if you check area51.

Comment: @Prix There is no "end of beta". And yes, it has multiple stats in the "Excellent" category. We are in no danger of being closed. Regardless, I still focus a lot of time on A&M, but there is no problem with driving other communities to success as well.